# React.memo shows an error when applied to js arrow function component

Tags: reactjs, webstorm, react-memo

The functional component:

```
const NewRestRequestCoreForm = props => {
    const intl = useIntl();
    ....
    return (
        <Container>
        ....
        </Container>
    );
}

export default React.memo(NewRestRequestCoreForm);
```

WebStorm shows me this error/warning:

```
Argument type function(any): JSX.Element is not assignable to parameter type SFC<object> ...
Type function(any): JSX.Element is not assignable to type FunctionComponent<object>
Type JSX.Element is not assignable to type ReactElement<any, any> | null
```

I simply want to cache this component so when the parent changes but the props passed to `NewRestRequestCoreForm` don't, `NewRestRequestCoreForm` does not get re-rendered.

The component is used like this:

```
<NewRestRequestCoreForm a={a}/>
```

What I'm doing wrong and how can I fix this?

**EDIT:**

I just used a simple Component with and without applying memo and it **works** even with the warning!

Comment: which version of react are you working with ?

Comment: "react": "16.13.1",

Comment: i think the problem is not related to the React.memo

Comment: could it be a bug in webstorm?

Comment: can you provide your jsconfig.json please

Comment: I just used a simple Component with and without applying memo and it works even with the warning! I think it's just webstorm.